# Is node.js + express (back-end) + emberjs (client) a reasonable stack for my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, express

To preface; I'm an experienced web developer, though I have barely used `nodejs`, and have not yet had the opportunity to work with `emberjs` (though I've done a decent amount of work with backbone).

I'm about to start a project to build a web based writing application (literature). In theory, the user would potentially have the application open for long periods of time, perhaps leaving it on. I intend to develop an expanding functionality set over time, which I would like to be able to drop into different places with relative ease. For example, perhaps develop a character list which I could then include in many places. I'm keen on using `emberjs` for the experimentation alone, but it also sounds like a good client side framework for the job.

I've looked at `django` briefly (haven't used it much before), but given that I'd like to use `emberjs`, it seems like `django` isn't a great choice as I'd be opting not to use many of its most compelling features.

Would writing my server side code in `nodejs` + `express` be a reasonable choice? The web application itself will have common features like login, admin, different permissions for users/tasks (eventually) - but I also anticipate some more beefy stuff.

Comment: node+express is not a reasonable choice, is THE choice. Mandatory.

Comment: and node+express+ember is more than THE choice :) go for it...

Comment: nodejs for anything other than simple i/o processing is **insane** (callback hell, etc). Emberjs doesn't care much about the backend, so you could choose any ruby/python/php framework.

Comment: I'm using this stack on my current project and so far it's working for me. You might consider using something like http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/ in place of express

Comment: @MattBerkowitz is your current project public on github or anything? I'd be curious to read some code for such a thing. Other than hello-world examples everywhere, I'm flying a bit blind.

Comment: @csjohn It's not up in a public place, but shoot me an email and I can send you some tonight when I'm home. I won't pretend it's the greatest code I've written in my life, but hopefully you can get something out of it!

Comment: Having lots of experience with Django *and* Node/Express, I'm choosing the latter :) Just more fun than Django IMO.

Comment: I'm thinking of rolling Node.js(Express) to serve the REST API that ember(ember-data) will consume. Then to serve templates and all static resources from an nginx server. Should be a recipe for a rocket-fuel powered modern web app. :-)

Comment: @MattBerkowitz Sounds great - unless I'm a dunce and missing the obvious, I don't know your email address, nor could I see it in your SOF profile :).

Comment: @csjohn hmm it's there when I look at my own profile, I guess I just assumed everyone could see it. berkowitz.matthew @ gmail

Comment: @MattBerkowitz Cheers, I sent you an email - let me know if you didn't receive it and I'll "try again". Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works well for my team and I so far. While lacking express, [Charcoal](https://github.com/thomasboyt/charcoal) is a good starter project to get up and running with Ember without a Rails asset pipeline and Express can easily be added as middleware. In addition to using Express to serve your JSON, it can handle the minimal HTML needed for such requirements that Ember can't fulfill by itself such as SEO since content negotiation capability [is very simple in Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/content-negotiation).